# Kак называется профессия?

Tags: значение-слов

Как называется должность, профессия человека, который смотрит на определенный объект и предлагает свои идеи, что можно построить (ресторан, кафе, отель, детский сад и т. п.), при этом предоставив заранее схему данного объекта (как бы свою идею как схему, а не описанную словами)?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, у нас называется это "инжене́р-строи́тель"

Comment: ... or what about this one "инженер-проектировщик"?

Comment: Инженер-строитель принимает решение о том, какие строительные материалы будут применяться.

Comment: ИНЖЕНЕР-ПРОЕКТИРОВЩИК разрабатывает отдельные части проекта, см. https://guide_positions.academic.ru/108/%d0%98%d0%9d%d0%96%d0%95%d0%9d%d0%95%d0%a0-%d0%9f%d0%a0%d0%9e%d0%95%d0%9a%d0%a2%d0%98%d0%a0%d0%9e%d0%92%d0%a9%d0%98%d0%9a

Answer (score 1):

**[Урбанистика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)**

Профессия - урбанист (в Вашем вопросе перечислены только городские объекты).

> Урбанистика – это не архитектура или градостроительство, всё намного
>   сложнее. Дело в том, что город – это не набор самостоятельных единиц,
>   как многие ошибочно полагают, а сложная система, состоящая из
>   множества единиц, которые непрерывно взаимодействуют друг с другом.
>   Хотя посмею назвать это сложной системой внутри ещё более сложной
>   системы – настолько в городе всё взаимосвязано. Именно это
>   взаимодействие и изучает урбанистика.

**[подробно](https://gre4ark.livejournal.com/326482.html)**

> Урбанист — это специалист по городскому планированию, умеющий сделать
>   городскую среду комфортной для проживания. Сферы его интересов могут
>   быть различны. Это и архитектура, и ландшафтный дизайн — в этом случае
>   урбанистом называют человека, который умеет грамотно вписать новое
>   здание в существующий ландшафт, разбить парк там, где это нужно
>   местным жителям, и так, как это им нужно. Урбанист может быть в
>   большей степени связан с социологией города — тогда он будет
>   заниматься, например, дизайном детских площадок, способствующих
>   уменьшению детской агрессии, местными сообществами, адаптацией
>   диаспор.

**[подробно](https://postupi.online/professiya/urbanist/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Архите́ктор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) — квалифицированный специалист, который на профессиональной основе осуществляет архитектурное проектирование (организацию архитектурной среды), включая проектирование зданий, в том числе разработку объёмно-планировочных и интерьерных решений.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: там архитектор есть

Comment: это совсем другая профессия

Comment: Возможно, Вам подойдет *дизайнер*. Это более общее понятие, чем архитектор (каждый архитектор – дизайнер, но не каждый дизайнер – архитектор), существует дизайнер одежды, например.

Comment: И где это "там" ("там архитектор есть")?